# How to create a dynamic documentation for an existing graphql-schema?

Tags: graphql

We want to create a documentation file for our existing graphql-schema (which we then would include into our application).
Right now we export a schema.graphql and then create a .md file with graphql-markdown.

Want we would like to achieve is that the created documentation could ignore some objects or properties, maybe similar to the deprecated field. The final document-file should now only include the objects which were not marked to be ignored.

How could we do this?

I've searched for already existing solutions or documentation software like Swagger.

Answer (score 0):

You could prefix the descriptions for types and fields you want to exclude using some arbitrary string, for example `@Hidden`. Then just fork `graphql-markdown` and modify it to exclude those objects and fields [here](https://github.com/exogen/graphql-markdown/blob/master/src/renderSchema.js#L134):

```
function isIgnored(typeOrField) {
  return typeOrField.description.startsWith('@Hidden')
}

const objects = types.filter(type => {
  return type.kind === 'OBJECT' && type !== query && type !== mutation && !isIgnored(type)
})
```

and [here](https://github.com/exogen/graphql-markdown/blob/master/src/renderSchema.js#L52):

```
const fields = (isInputObject ? type.inputFields : type.fields)
  .filter(field => !isIgnored(field))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll definitely try that.